# How to select all values that have the same chronological order?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm saving all the moves a player does in a Table with the associated Game-Id.

The order in which the moves are executed is also saved.

**Table:**

```
id | move     | order
---+----------+------
 1 | Attack   | 1
 1 | Defense  | 2
 1 | Defense  | 3
 1 | Fly      | 4
 2 | Attack   | 1
```

For example: In game ID 1 he first Attack,Defense,Defense then Fly.

I now want to select all game-id's that have the same chronological order I specified.

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Table
WHERE Player 
first Attack
second Defense
third Defense
```

The Pseudo Code would for example return ID 1 even thought the fourth move Fly wasn't specified.

Comment: . . I find your question is little unclear.  What do *you* mean by "same chronological order"?  Do you mean starting with the same three moves?  The same three moves in any position but adjacent?  The three moves in that order but there could be intermediate moves as well?

Comment: Yes starting with the same three moves. Thanks for your answer<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that you want the same initial set of moves, then I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(move ORDER BY "order") as moves
      FROM t
      WHERE order <= 3
     ) im
WHERE moves = ARRAY['Attack', 'Defense', 'Defense'];
```

This is only checking the first three moves.  You might also phrase this as:

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(move ORDER BY "order") as moves
      FROM t
      WHERE order <= CARDINALITY(ARRAY['Attack', 'Defense', 'Defense'])
     ) im
WHERE moves = ARRAY['Attack', 'Defense', 'Defense'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select id
from (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by "order") rn from mytable t) t
group by id
having
    max(case when rn = 1 and move = 'Attack' then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when rn = 2 and move = 'Defense' then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when rn = 3 and move = 'Defense' then 1 end) = 1
```

Side note: `order` is not a wise column name, since it clashes with a reserved work in all RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the moves in comma separated list like: `'Attack,Defense,Defense,Fly'` and you want all the game ids with the same order you can do it with [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select "id"
from tablename
group by "id"
having string_agg("move", ',' order by "order") = 'Attack,Defense,Defense,Fly'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fxub3wyMoVNkAhUgoXfR4G/0).
Results (for your sample data):

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an ordered [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) inside a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT id, array_agg(move ORDER BY "order") AS moves FROM t GROUP BY id 
) SELECT id FROM j WHERE moves = '{Attack,Defense,Defense,Fly}';

 id 
----
  1
(1 Zeile)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generic solution, You can try something like

```
Select
    Id,
    max(first)  m1,
    max(second) m2,
    max(third)  m3,
    max(fourth) m4
from 
(Select
     Id, 
     Case when order = 1 then move else "" as first
     Case when order = 2 then move else "" as second
     Case when order = 3 then move else "" as third
     Case when order = 4 then move else "" as fourth
 From table) as flat_table
Group by id
```

This will give you a table where you can apply where conditions on move number or group by move patterns etc. It is pretty inefficient but is very flexible.

If you need a more efficient solution then apply where clauses while selecting from the inner table itself.